# how to get the response content with dispatch?

Tags: scala, scala-dispatch

I have looked at the dispatch tutorial, and can easily find how to get the header information (if the status is 200, if I have understood other posts) for instance with;

```
def main(args: Array[String]){ 
    val svc = url("http://www.google.com")
    val country = Http(svc OK as.String)
    for (c <- country){
        println(c)
    }
}
```

However, I can not find how to get the response content. I would be thankful if someone could help me with that. I assume it should be a function applied on svc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation explains it:

> The above defines and initiates a request to the given host where 2xx
>   responses are handled as a string. Since Dispatch is fully
>   asynchronous, **country represents a future of the string** rather than
>   the string itself.

(emphasis mine) where `country` refers to the request from your example and your example actually returns the body.

Note that your code example explicitely casts into `String`, but you can get the raw response object like this:

```
val svc = url("http://www.google.com")
val request = Http(svc)
val response = request()
print(s"Status\n  ${response.getStatusCode}\nHeaders:\n  ${response.getHeaders}\nBody:\n  ${response.getResponseBody}")
```

This gets you the HTTP status code, all response headers and the entire response body.

[See the entire reference for the Response here](https://asynchttpclient.github.io/async-http-client/apidocs/com/ning/http/client/Response.html)

Comment: I read the tutorial so fully aware that it is a future of the string and not the string itself. The other stuff you wrote could be useful.